# Mobile slide menu with fixed topbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, mobile

I'm using a slide menu for mobile on my responsive website. The problem is that when you scroll down and then you click on the open-menu button, the page jumps to the top, instead of staying in the same position that you click on the open-menu button.

Here the code that I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/miscky/35shP/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{
    margin:0;
    }
#nav{
    width:75%;
    left:-75%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    background:#000;
}
#nav a{
    color:#fff;
}
#mobTopBar{
    width:96%;
    padding:2%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:999;
    background:#ededed;
}
#mobTopBar a{
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px;
    background:#333;
}
#content-wrapper{
    background:#fff;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:96%;
    padding:2%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    }
.open-menu,
.open-menu #content-wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}

</style>

            <header>

            <div id="mobTopBar">
                <a href="#" id="menu" class="ico-menu">Menu</a>
            </div>

            <nav id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Button 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Button 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Button 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Button 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Button 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Button 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Button 8</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </header>

        <div id="content-wrapper">

            <section>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dictum, dolor id tempor cursus, metus diam accumsan leo, sed lacinia risus est eu erat. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum erat nibh, eleifend vitae ultrices et, blandit in quam. Quisque dapibus volutpat dictum. Maecenas fringilla nisl vitae mauris venenatis, eget pharetra lectus auctor. Ut nisi urna, venenatis non mi ac, congue aliquam nibh. Donec ornare dictum lectus pellentesque suscipit. Vestibulum consequat hendrerit nunc sit amet molestie. Phasellus iaculis id turpis vel viverra. Fusce euismod sodales nunc ac fringilla. Nunc feugiat diam arcu, in bibendum nisi ornare id.</p>
            </section>
        </div>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  TriggerClick = 0;
  $('a#menu').click(function(){
    if(TriggerClick==0){
         TriggerClick=1;
         $('body').addClass('open-menu');
         $('#nav').animate({left:'0%'}, 200);
         $('#content-wrapper').animate({marginLeft:'75%'}, 200);
         $('#mobTopBar').animate({marginLeft:'75%'}, 200);
         $(window).resize(function() {
           $('body').height($(window).height());
           $('body').width($(window).width());
         });
         $(window).trigger('resize');
    }else{
         TriggerClick=0;
         $('body').removeClass('open-menu');
         $('#nav').animate({left:'-75%'}, 1);
         $('#content-wrapper').animate({marginLeft:'0%'}, 1);
         $('#mobTopBar').animate({marginLeft:'0%'}, 1);
         $(window).resize(function() {
           $('body').height('auto');
           $('body').width('auto');
         });
         $(window).trigger('resize');
    };

    return false;
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('#content-wrapper').height($(window).height());
    $('#nav').height($(window).height());
    $('#content-wrapper section').height($(window).height());
  });
  $(window).trigger('resize');

});
</script>
```

I've spent day trying to solve the following issue without succeed, so I'll really appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have I done wrong to don't receive a single message?

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove href="#" and replace with href="javascript:void(0)"- good practice when developing for mobile.

Second, please try (so what i am doing is that I am preventing the default action the browser has set to cancel it, this way when you click on a #menu it doesn't go to the top because when you normal click on anchor link it default action is to refresh the page or go to top (varies in different browsers)

```
$('#menu').on('click',function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault() ... //your remaning code

}
```